# How to connect a module with other module or simple module in OMNet++

Tags: omnet++

could you tell me how to connect module with other module or simple module in omnet++?, for example I have this module

```js
module R
{
    parameters:
        @display("bgb=151,47,white;i=device/palm;b=40,40,rect");
    gates:
        input in;
}
```

and this the simple module

```js
simple sender
{
    gates:
        output out;
        output out1;
        input in;
}
```

and there are two others with the same, and finally my connections

```js
connections:
  s.out --> r.in;
  s.out1 --> r1.in;// s is the simple module and r1 is the module
  r.out1 --> s1.in;
  r.out --> s.in;
}
```

but when I start simulation OMNet++ give me an error say that the input gate of the module r1 is not connected with any module or simple module. This was my problem, so if you have a help please tell me. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R is defined as a 'compound' module which means that it MUST have internal submodules that are connected to its gates. R - as currently defined - is empty so what is supposed to happen when something arrives to its 'in' gate? All gates on a compound module MUST be connected both the outside and the inside.

Comment: Ooh!!, that's really great, you helped me so much Mr. Rudi, thank very much. Mr. Rudi, may I ask you for help in the future if I have problems with OMNet++ and c++?, of course if I don't bother you sir.